# checking for double threshold

Tags: c++, qt

I've a basic question to implement an algorithm to detect a threshold for a realtime signal.

For ex. If I've a signal as shown below, I need to check if the signal crossing two thresholds in a fixed period of time, say 3 seconds.

[image]

My question here is, What will be set of IF statements to check for two thresholds in a fixed time period?

**What I've already got:**

I can check for a single threshold, as below:

```
if(signal > onThreshold)
   {    
       ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn1); // change appearance of a radio button 
       QSound::play(":/res/beep1.wav"); // make a beep sound as well    
   }
   else
   {
       ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff1);
   }
```

Comment: In a nutshell: when threshold is crossed, save the timestamp to a variable. When it is crossed again, check the current time against that timestamp.

Comment: Decompose the problem into a part that checks for an (upwards, i guess?) threshold crossing, then add a part that checks the timestamp as @Thomas suggested.

Comment: @Botje Hi , could you please show me logic with pseudo codes?

Comment: look at the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we create a helper that detects upwards crossings:

```
class DetectUpwardsCrossing : public QObject {
    public:
        DetectUpwardsCrossing(double threshold, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), threshold(threshold), current(qSNaN()) {}
        signals:
            void crossing();
        public slots:
            void onSignal(double value) {
                if (qIsNaN(current)) {
                    current = value;
                    return;
                }

                if (current == value) {
                    return;
                }

                bool before = current <= threshold;
                current = value;
                bool after = current >= threshold;
                if (before && after) {
                    emit crossing();
                }
            }
    private:
        double threshold, current;
};
```

Now create an instance of `DetectUpwardsCrossing`, hook up your incoming signal value to `onSignal` and hook its `crossing` signal to the following method:

```
void onCrossing() {
    QSound::play(":/res/beep1.wav"); // make a beep sound
    if (crossingTimer->isActive()) { // The timer is still running, so we are within the 3s period
        ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn1); // change appearance of a radio button
    }
    crossingTimer->restart();
}

void crossingTimerExpire() {
    ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff1);
    crossingTimer->stop();
}
```

The final piece is a `QTimer *crossingTimer` with an interval of 3 seconds, whose `timeout` signal is hooked up to `crossingTimerExpire`.

By using a timer like this, you can ensure that the display turns "off" if you suddenly no longer receive signals.